# Tomcat 8.0.30 Update change redirect behaviour

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8

I updated Tomcat 8 from 8.0.26 to 8.0.30.

In our project we use org.springframework:spring-webmvc:4.2.3.RELEASE.

With version 8.0.26 Tomcat sends an automatic redirect 302 when we open the context root: http://localhost:8080/vrk > http://localhost:8080/vrk/

Since version 8.0.30 the redirect is not send any more and this leads to some problems with relative URLs.

The Java configuration has not changed (we don't use XML in that project).

```
public final class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(final ServletContext servletContext) {
        try (
                final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext()) {
            rootContext.register(AppConfig.class);
            servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        }
        try (
                final AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext dispatcherContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext()) {
            dispatcherContext.register(WebConfig.class);
            // dispatcherContext.setServletContext(servletContext); I don't know the reason for this line
            final Dynamic dynamic = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher",
                    new DispatcherServlet(dispatcherContext));
            dynamic.setLoadOnStartup(1);
            dynamic.addMapping("/");
            dynamic.setMultipartConfig(
                    new MultipartConfigElement("/tmp", 1024 * 1024 * 5, 1024 * 1024 * 6, 1024 * 1024));
        }
    }

}
```

How can we restore the redirect behaviour?
Is this a bug in Tomcat 8.0.30?

Answer (score 1):

This bug seems related and offers a possible workaround:

https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58660

Comment: I tested it on 8.0.30. I added mapperContextRootRedirectEnabled="true" to the context.xml. It's still not redirecting :(. I want the redirect back.

Comment: That flag helped me. Though this change itself is weird - it impacts many people, but the devs are still not sure if it's expected or not.